# 4.3 Galaxy S4: how do I prevent keyboard backspace from deleting whole word?

Tags: keyboard, samsung-galaxy-s-4, 4.3-jelly-bean

I've just updated my Galaxy S4 (T-Mobile, in case that matters) from 4.2.2 to 4.3.  Now when using the keyboard (default settings), if I get to the end of a word -- either strictly on my own or via one of its suggestions -- and then backspace, it deletes the whole word.  Before, backspacing at that point deleted one character at a time.  Often it's faster for me to correct a suggestion (or notice and fix a typo of mine) this way than to start over with that word.  I'd like my phone to stop being so aggressive in cleaning up after me.

I don't remember setting something for this in the previous version (though it's been a while).  I've walked through the settings for the device and in Twitter and Messaging (the apps where I've noticed this behavior so far), but haven't found anything that seems relevant.  I have not rooted my phone and don't plan to.

Current settings, under Device -> Language & Input:

- Default: Samsung keyboard
- Samsung keyboard settings:

  - predictive text: on
  - auto replacement: off
  - auto capitalization: on
  - auto spacing: on
  - auto punctuate: off
- Keyboard Swipe:

  - SwiftKey Flow on
  - Cursor Control off

Aside from auto punctuate (which I turned off), these settings are as they came after the upgrade.

Comment: SwiftKey has never done this for me on any version of android on an S4... Swype does it by default.. I've just tried it here and it doesn't do it in any of those apps... Maybe reinstall your keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never got this working (and didn't download a different keyboard), but I recently received the update for 4.4.4 and it's working now.  So I don't know if it was something specific to Samsung (or my provider, T-Mobile), but the whole-word deletion has stopped.

Answer (score 0):

If I may, I suggest KK Keyboard. I'm not advertising, but I use it myself, because my keyboard did this too.