# How do I delete an incorrectly auto-completed word with backspace?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, keyboard, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I use Samsung's default keyboard for typing. Specifically, I use the Swype-like part of it, SwiftKey Flow.

I recently updated my Samsung Galaxy S5 to Android Marshmallow, and I noticed that a feature I liked about SwiftKey was changed/removed. Previously, when I would swipe across the keyboard to "type" words, if the predicted word was incorrect, I could hit backspace *once* and that would delete the word.

That is also how my Galaxy S3 worked before I got the S5. When I type on a computer, I hardly ever delete things a character at a time. I delete the entire word with Ctrl+Backspace, and I really liked this type of thing on my phone too.

Following the Marshmallow update, if I mis-swipe a word and hit backspace, it only deletes one letter. This causes me some grief because then I have to hit backspace many times if the word was long, or hold the backspace key and risk deleting more than intended. In addition, I am so used to the previous behavior that I don't realize the word is incorrect, and I keep typing a gibberish word.

Is there a way to reintroduce this feature? Note that this is not the same as [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/81494/4-3-galaxy-s4-how-do-i-prevent-keyboard-backspace-from-deleting-whole-word), and is in fact the opposite thing entirely.

I have tried looking in Samsung keyboard settings under Predictive text, Auto replace, and Keyboard swipe (all that does is let you *select* SwiftKey Flow, but not change anything about it), but I didn't see anything that lets me change this.